# HTML file rendering in Chrome

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to export some data on purpose from SQL Server as an HTML file, but Internet explores is rendering those files perfectly fine though chrome displays special characters.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
        td {
            border: solid black 0px; 
            padding-left:5px;
            padding-right:5px; 
            padding-top:1px; 
            padding-bottom:1px; 
            font-size:8pt;
            font-family:Arial;
            } 
        td.thickBorder { 
            border-top: solid #000 1px;
        }
        td.thickTBBorder { 
            border-top: solid #000 1px; 
            border-bottom:solid #000 1px; 
            padding-left:5px; 
            padding-right:5px;
            padding-top:1px;
            padding-bottom:1px;
            font-size:8pt; 
            font-family:Arial;
        } 
        .style1 {
            font-size:14pt; font-weight: bold;
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Export as `UTF-8 Without BOM`

Comment: jiff i am using this query where do i mention UTF-8 wihtout BOM  "EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT body FROM [dbo].[COPYTABLE] WHERE [Number] =700"  queryout "C:\Updates\AAMN\1740.html" -T -N -SPV3'

GO

Comment: What is the character between the '<' and the 'h' in html? Semantically, there should be no additional character there.  Likewise, semantically, there should be no additional character anywhere where the � is showing up.  SPECULATION: When this string is being built, the opening bracket is being added with a char(0) byte in it. Depending on how a browser handles those incorrect zero-byte characters, they could either be ignored or be displayed this way. Can you verify the byte value there?

Comment: I did there is no character in between < and h.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in <head> tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: can you please share a site link here